# How to fit zoom to a bounding box in OpenGlobus?

Tags: 3d, gis, openglobus

I'm porting some Leaflet map code to OpenGlobus and would like to have the camera zoom to a bounding box.

Leaflet code looks like this:

```
    map.fitBounds([

      [ data.boundingbox[0], data.boundingbox[2] ],
      [ data.boundingbox[1], data.boundingbox[3] ]

    ]);
```

I suspect I need to use createBoundsByExtent() and then zoom to the bounds.
A short example would help me here. I tried to grep through the examples for that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the example for cameras View Extent [View extent example](http://openglobus.org/examples/cameraFly/cameraFly.html)

```
planet.viewExtent/flyExtent(extent)
```

where extent type of Extent